# Why did i get access array offset value on type null?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to get a user details from the database and compare it with   the posted value. Now I get **Trying to access array offset on value of type null in**. The column name *user_number* exists in the database.
This is my code below.. Thanks!!!

```
     <?php
     mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

     error_reporting(E_ALL | E_WARNING | E_NOTICE);

     ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);

      if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
  session_start();

    }
     if(!isset($_SESSION['login']))
     {
     echo ("<script>location.href='../clogin/'</script>");
     die();
     }

     if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
      {
      

        include_once('db.php');
       //get post details from user
             
        $UserNumber = $_POST['uNumber'];

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM customer WHERE user_number=?";   
        $stmt = $connection->prepare($sql); 
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $UserNumber);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        $count =  $result->num_rows;
      if($count == 1)
       { 
   
       while($row = $result->fetch_assoc());

         {


         $db_Uno = $row['user_number'];



           if($userNumber !== $db_Uno) 
           {


             
  echo'<script>swal.fire("FAILED!!", "<strong>No Customer with the user number you entered.</strong><hr><br/><i> Check well and try Again.</i>", "error");window.setTimeout(function(){
   window.location.href = "home.php";
   }, 2000);</script>'; 

             exit();
             }

              else
              {
               }


                 }//while loop
          
                  } //end of if rslt     


                    }// end submit for transfer post        
          
                      ?>
```

Sorry to ask such a newbie question. I have tried to fix it for several hours. Still the same error.

Comment: Which row is causing the error? My guess is that the method call $stmt->bind_param('i', UserNumber); is missing a $ sign for the variable UserNumber: $stmt->bind_param('i', $UserNumber);

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. The $ is there

Comment: At d point, $db_Uno = $row['user_number']; it can't read the value in the database. When I tried to echo $db_Uno, I get that same error